# Sealed 12V lead-acid battery, cycle voltage 15V: supplied charger unfit?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

My lawnmower's starting battery is a sealed lead-acid 12V cube with "Cycle: 14.4-15.0V" printed on it.

The simple molex-tipped wall charger that was supplied with the mower says "OUTPUT 12V DC".

The problem is that it's taking about 3 whole days for the charger to charge the battery.

Am I correct in thinking this charger isn't a good fit for the battery, and I should get some third-party 15-Volter, and my manufacturer (Partner) is somehow an idiot? Or is it that the charger could be a 15-Volter (I don't have the means to check now), only mislabeled as 12V, really meaning "for a 12V battery"?

Comment: Without seeing the charger it's hard to tell but it's possible that the charger is just supplying float voltage since they know you're only going to use the starter battery very briefly once or twice a week and probably leave it plugged in the rest of the time.  3 days to charge the battery isn't a huge deal if you are only discharging it for two seconds every Saturday.

Comment: Having to keep the mower plugged in for "the rest of the time" doesn't sound practical.

Comment: Keeping the charger connected all the time is the very definition/use-case for a float-charger.

Answer (score 2):

12V is the **nominal** voltage for a 12V Lead-acid battery. Measuring a fully charged lead-acid battery will indicate 13.2 to 13.6V. The lead-acid battery is considered discharged at 11V. So the 12V label is just a label for identifcation purposes. They are often charged with a charger capable of 14.4-15V.

The charger supplied with the lawnmower is no different and will work.

Comment: "often charged with a charger capable of 14.4-15V" ... but mine is rated at 12V.

Also, I wouldn't be asking the question if the charger did its job. It takes it like 3 days to charge the battery to any workable state.

Comment: Your charger is "ladeled as 12V" . A lead acid battery cannot charge at that voltage. It may still capable of 14 to 15 volts,but is current limited to a lower current or it is broken. The lawnmower manual should indicate the time to full charge, Check with the manufacturer.

Comment: @SinustheTentacular it's not a 12V charger, it's a charger for 12V batteries (which are 13ish volts when full and 11ish volts when empty)

Comment: So why would the charger be labeled "INPUT 230V AC, OUTPUT 12V DC"?

Comment: @SinustheTentacular because if it were labeled as 14.5Vdc then people would worry about using it on their 12V batteries...